# Paragraph (5) of section 7.3 in Fulton's Algebraic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A little background on notation:

[image]

and here is paragraph (5):

[image]

On to my question now: It seems to me that there is some inconsistency in the highlighted text. In particular, if $\lambda=0$, then i don't see how the point $Q=[0:1]$ is inside $\phi(W')$. Moreover, it seems that in writing $\phi(W')$ as $B$ minus some closed sets, it should really be $V(Y_{11})$ instead of $V(Y_{12})$. What do you think about that?

If i was to mend the situation, then i would simply take the point $Q$ to be $Q=[1:\lambda]$, with $\lambda=0$ if necessary, and i would replace  $V(Y_{12})$with $V(Y_{11})$. Does that sound reasonable?